# Reducing a resultant table to only values that are less than 10%

Tags: sql, mysql, statistics, mysql-workbench, metrics

I am trying to get a metric of my database of 'relationships' that are found in less than 10% of 'sources'. I have successfully created a table that has every relationship, as well as the corresponding percentage of sources each relationship is found in. Below is my code:

```
use rt_database;
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
#Used the code above to ensure ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode is deactivated for my grouping

SELECT observations.`Relationship ID`, 
        ROUND((COUNT(statements.`Source ID`) / 
        (SELECT COUNT(sources.`Source ID`) from sources)),3) * 100
        AS "Ubiquity Percentage"
FROM statements
JOIN observations ON statements.`Old Observation ID` = observations.`Old Obs ID`
GROUP BY observations.`Relationship ID`
#HAVING "Ubiquity Percentage" < 10 
#The line above is what I thought would successfully limit my table to only relationships less than 10%
ORDER BY observations.`Relationship ID`
;
```

The code above works perfectly in getting me a complete table with each relationship and it's corresponding percentage. However, when I uncomment the HAVING line, no changes are made to the table. And if I edit the HAVING line to say `HAVING "Ubiquity Percentage" > 10` , then the table output is completely empty. Below is a screenshot of the current results I'm getting:

[image: Current Resultant Table]

Would love some help. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` since there are no columns other than the one you're grouping by and the aggregated value.

Comment: Use backticks, not double quotes, in the `HAVING` clause. You're comparing the literal string, not the column.

Comment: And when you compare the string, it converts to `0`, and `0 < 10` is always true.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! So simple, I feel dumb for not catching that. That fixed the problem.

Comment: It's an understandable mistake if you learned standard SQL. Using double quotes for strings is a MySQL extension.

Comment: @Barmar Do you happen to know how I can now edit the code to only show me the COUNT of all the percentages less than 10%, instead of showing me each one?

Comment: Wrap the whole query in `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your query) AS x`

Comment: Note that with your having uncommented, it will generate a warning "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Ubiquity Percentage'".  https://dbfiddle.uk/bLuXCRnL When testing/debugging, do consider using a client that at least shows you when there are warnings; I like the mysql command line client.